# Hyperref Doesn't link \cite Command

Tags: hyperref, cite-package, ieeeconf

I am using latex to hyperlink my citations in an article.
The problem is that it links figures, equations and sections numbers but not citation links. Here's a MWE,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              
\overrideIEEEmargins                                     % Needed to meet printer requirements.
\usepackage{hyperref}                                   %hyperlink your equations and figures and sorts
\usepackage{times}                                       % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    %assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}                                     % assumes amsmath 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{footnote}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=green}

\title{\LARGE \bf
Some Title*
 }

\author{Author One$^{1}$, Author 2$^{2}$    % <-this % stops a space
\begin{document}
\long\def\/*#1*/{}                              % Define block comment

\graphicspath{ {Chart and Figures/} }

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}


  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
Some Random Abstract.

{\textit{Index Terms} - Life Science and Health Care; Mechatronics; Emerging      Topics in Automation }
\end{abstract}   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}

Results from the clinical studies \cite{cervino, c2, c3} serve as motivation   for minimizing patient positioning errors during IGRT in order to minimize   positioning-related uncertainties in cancer dose treatments, improve tumor   control, and reduce toxicity \cite{c4, c5}.

\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{cervino} Cervino, L.I., Pawlicki, T., Lawson, J.D., Jiang, S.B., Frame-less and mask-less cranial stereotactic radiosurgery: a feasibility study. Phys. Med. Biol. 55 (2010) 1863-1873.
\bibitem{c2} Xing, L., Dosimetric effects of patient displacement and  collimator and gantry angle misalignment on intensity modulated radiation  therapy. Radiother Oncol, 2000. 56(1): p. 97-108.
\bibitem{c3} Manning, M.A., et al., The effect of setup uncertainty on normal tissue sparing with IMRT for head-and-neck cancer. Int J Radiat Oncol Biol Phys, 2001. 51(5): p. 1400-9.
\bibitem{c4} Hong, T.S., et al., The impact of daily setup variations on head-and-neck intensity-modulated radiation therapy. Int J Radiat Oncol Biol Phys, 2005. 61(3): p. 779-88.
\bibitem{c5} Den, R.B., et al., Daily image guidance with cone-beam computed tomography for head-and-neck cancer intensity-modulated radiotherapy: a prospective study. Int J Radiat Oncol Biol Phys, 2010. 76(5): p. 1353-9.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

But I find that my \cite citations are not hyper-ref'd. Is there a workaround this? Would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Usually hyperref should be imported last, you could try that.

Comment: @Matt Tried that. No luck!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It has been 2 years since this question was asked, but I will write my solution because I had the same problem.

As suggested by many, `hyperref` should be imported last.  I also tried that but failed  to hyperlink my citations in the document. So, the problem is with the `ieeeconf.cls`. If you open it with the latex editor you are using you'll see the following:

```
% 2) Provide a fake nabib command \NAT@parse so that hyperref will not
%    interfere with the operation of cite.sty. However, as a result citation
%    numbers will not be hyperlinked. Also, natbib will not be able to work
%    with IEEEtran. However, this is perhaps the best solution until cite.sty
%    and hyperref.sty are able to co-exist with each other.
%    It easy enough to override the fake command via:
%    \makeatletter
%    \let\NAT@parse\undefined
%    \makeatother
```

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              
\overrideIEEEmargins                                     % Needed to meet printer requirements.

\usepackage{times}                                       % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    %assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}                                     % assumes amsmath 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{footnote}

\makeatletter
\let\NAT@parse\undefined
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}  %hyperref still needs to be put at the end!

\title{\LARGE \bf
Some Title*
}

\author{Author One$^{1}$, Author Two$^{2}$    % <-this % stops a space
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
 Some Random Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

 Results from the \cite{a}, \cite{b}, \cite{c} serve as motivation...

\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{a} First reference
\bibitem{b} Second reference
\bibitem{c} Third reference

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I just included the three lines suggested in the cls file. As  Schweinebacke remarked, this is  for the old version of `ieeeconf.cls`.

Comment: This is about the old [`ieeeconf.cls`](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/files/ieeeconf.cls) not the current `IEEEconf.cls` from [`IEEEconf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/IEEEconf), isn't it?

Comment: Would be good to add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show that this works.

Comment: @Shweinebacke, you are correct. But in my case, I just downloaded the ieeeconf.cls file from the conference website. Apparently, they use the old version. So, probably just updating the files works.

Comment: awesome! thanks for figuring this out! This fixes the problem for ieeeconf.cls. I did not realize there is an up-to-date version called IEEEconf.cls.

Answer (score 4):

Your code contain several errors.  In my MWE below I corrected them. The main errors are marked with `<============`.

Some remarks:

- The `hyperref` has to be (except in rare cases) the **last** package in the preamble.
- Your command `\begin{thebibliography}` is not correct. It has to has a length parameter for the labels like `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`.
- The `\bf` is outdated. Use `\textbf{...}` instead or `\bfseries`.
- I commented your two IEEE commands, they are unknown in the class I have.
- Your command `\author{}` was not closed with a `}`.
- Define block element is not needed for the MWE (BTW: Why do you use it?)
- Preamble of your MWE contain several packages (`amsmath`, `footnote`, ...) not used in your code. Since they are not related to the your problem, you can omit them!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} % IEEEconf
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              
%\overrideIEEEmargins     % Needed to meet printer requirements.

\usepackage{times}    % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath 

\usepackage{xcolor} % <======================================= for green
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{hyperref} % <====================== last packge to be called
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor=green}

\title{\LARGE 
\textbf{Some Title}*
 }

\author{Author One$^{1}$, Author 2$^{2}$} % <================= missing }

\begin{document}
\long\def\/*#1*/{}                              % Define block comment

\graphicspath{ {Chart and Figures/} }

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
Some Random Abstract.

{\textit{Index Terms}~-- Life Science and Health Care; Mechatronics; 
Emerging      Topics in Automation}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Results from the clinical studies \cite{cervino, c2, c3} serve as 
motivation   for minimizing patient positioning errors during IGRT in 
order to minimize   positioning-related uncertainties in cancer dose 
treatments, improve tumor   control, and reduce toxicity \cite{c4, c5}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99} % <==================== length missing! {99}
\bibitem{cervino} Cervino, L.I., Pawlicki, T., Lawson, J.D., Jiang, S.B., Frame-less and mask-less cranial stereotactic radiosurgery: a feasibility study. Phys. Med. Biol. 55 (2010) 1863-1873.
\bibitem{c2} Xing, L., Dosimetric effects of patient displacement and  collimator and gantry angle misalignment on intensity modulated radiation  therapy. Radiother Oncol, 2000. 56(1): p. 97-108.
\bibitem{c3} Manning, M.A., et al., The effect of setup uncertainty on normal tissue sparing with IMRT for head-and-neck cancer. Int J Radiat Oncol Biol Phys, 2001. 51(5): p. 1400-9.
\bibitem{c4} Hong, T.S., et al., The impact of daily setup variations on head-and-neck intensity-modulated radiation therapy. Int J Radiat Oncol Biol Phys, 2005. 61(3): p. 779-88.
\bibitem{c5} Den, R.B., et al., Daily image guidance with cone-beam computed tomography for head-and-neck cancer intensity-modulated radiotherapy: a prospective study. Int J Radiat Oncol Biol Phys, 2010. 76(5): p. 1353-9.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

I would suggest to use `biblatex` with a `bib` file.

Comment: Interesting. I tried your suggestions doing everything you have commanded :). I still got the pdf without link borders. Maybe it has something to do with my Latex setup. I am using TeXstudio, if it helps.

Comment: Okay. I will check later this evening. Got to finish up a project right now.

Comment: I have no idea why it does not come out after trying all your suggestions. I bow out --ungracefully!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer to the original question, but it might still save someone a couple of minutes:

- Another reason for links not appearing can be that the document is in draft mode. Double check that this is not the case `\documentclass[draft,...]{...}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. You can change the color values to whatever color you like.

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `natbib` package with `hyperref`. With the `natbib` package, you will have also `\citep` and `\citet` commands available.