# llncs: Use of hyperref removes space between citations

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, hyperref, citing, lncs

I use the Springer LNCS format and observed that spaces between multiple citations get lost if I use the hyperref package. How can I fix that?

Result without hyperref package: `[1, 2]`

Result with hyperref package: `[1,2]`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

%\usepackage[bookmarks=false,hidelinks]{hyperref} 

\begin{document} 
\cite{ref_1,ref_2}

\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\bibitem{ref_1}
R1

\bibitem{ref_2}
R2

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

`\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` does *not* fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent `hyperref` from interfering with the `cite` command. You can do this by defining a fake `natbib` command, `\NAT@parse`, as discussed in a [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396390).

Then, `\usepackage{cite}` (with or without `noadjust`) is sufficient to resolve the spacing issue, if you are okay with its overriding the `llncs` internal `cite` macro.

I have created a demo of this on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qrbtpymcbbtw).