# How to add hyperlink for a reference in the text

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I want to add reference link in the text so that by clicking on that I can go at the end in the reference section on that particular reference. For example, The example is given in [1] (this 1 should be hyperlinked). How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us a short compilable TeX code we can play with and do not forget to add two bib entries into your question ...

Comment: You can achieve by using the combination of packages `hyperref` and `natbib`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279886/221473 is what I am looking for but with a color different from green

Comment: just adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` should make `[1]` a link you can specify the colours used via package options

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{new bib name} %uncoment it if You want to change the name of bibliography part


\lipsum[1]\cite{lit1}


\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{9}% this number shows You how many sourses can You use (now You can use up to 9)
\bibitem{lit1} Your author here.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```